# Cannot customize ggplot x-axis tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to coerce the ticks of the x-axis to be the individual characters in a character vector. How can this be accomplished?

I've tried:

```
char.list <- c('a','l','t','e','r','e','d')
times <- c(1:7)    
df <- as.data.frame(list('chars'=char.list, 'times'=times))
g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=1:length(char.list), y=times)) +
      scale_x_discrete("Characters",breaks=char.list, 
                       labels=char.list) + 
      geom_point(aes(size=10, colour='red'))
```

When I try @Heroka's code, this results in:

[image]

Comment: Does this not do what you want? `ggplot(data=df, aes(x = chars, y=times)) + geom_point(aes(size=10, colour='red'))`

Comment: You posted before and deleted. Still unsure- do you want two ticks with 'e' in this case?

Comment: @Heroka - sorry about before. i was able to get a single value for each point using scale_x_discrete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=1:length(char.list), y=times)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=10, colour='red'))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:length(char.list), labels=char.list)
```

produces

[image]